# O inicializador de tipo de 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' acionou uma exceção com c#

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, connectionstring

Meu programa wpf funcionava muito bem. Mexeram, para fazer algumas alterações. Bem, aí me pediram para alterar umas pastas no aplicativo. Antes de eu fazer qualquer alteração fui rodar a aplicação e está me dando esse erro:

> O inicializador de tipo de 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection'
>   acionou uma exceção

O fato ocorre nessa linha:

```
var diferenca = _listaCommiter().Except(_listaFarm());
```

Esse é o código completo do método:

```
private List<string> RetornaDiferenca()
{
    List<string> listaDiferenca = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        var diferenca = _listaCommiter().Except(_listaFarm());

        foreach (var _diferenca in diferenca)
        {
            listaDiferenca.Add(_diferenca);
        }

        diferenca = null;

        return listaDiferenca;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string r = ex.Message;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Esse é o método `_listaFarm()`

```
private List<string> _listaFarm()
{
    List<string> lista = new List<string>();

    ConexaoBanco cb = new ConexaoBanco();

    lista = cb.CriaConexao();

    return lista;
}
```

É um select em uma tablea do BD.

Percebi que no método onde pego a conexão, é que tá dando o problema. Esse é o método:

```
public List<string> CriaConexao()
{
    string conexao = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FarmExternaConnect"]
                .ConnectionString;
    List<string> listaArquivoFarmExterna = new List<string>();

    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(conexao);
    conn.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "select path, arquivo from gh_arquivos_farm_externa";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    try
    {
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            listaArquivoFarmExterna.Add(dr.GetString(0) + dr.GetString(1));
        }

        return listaArquivoFarmExterna;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

O erro dá nessa linha:
`OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(conexao);`

Esse é o inner exception:

> The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Minha string de conexão:

```
<add name="FarmExternaConnect" connectionString="Data Source=DESENV; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=Eu; Password=teste"/>
```

Mais linhas no meu app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework"
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx"
      requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client"
      type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- Pastas de Projetos .NET que estão na Farm Externa, separados por vírgula -->
    <add key="ProjetosDotNet" value="teste"/>
  </appSettings>

   <connectionStrings>
     <add name="FarmExternaConnect" connectionString="Data Source=DESENV; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=user; Password=teste"/>
   </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
        type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.121.2.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) "/>
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tirei o TNS e fiz o sistema buscar pelo servidor e dessa forma consegui a conexão com o banco e funcionou. Essa é a forma que eu encontrei: `<add name="FarmExternaConnect" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=nome_do_servidor)(PORT=1521))(C‌​ONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));User id=user;Password=teste;"/>`

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver dessa forma? Se sim, marca ela como resposta para que outros possam tirar proveito da solução :)

Comment: Só posso fazer após dois dias. Regras do site.

Answer (score 1):

@pnet, se você mostrar o erro exato que está sendo gerado (se possível o `Stacktrace`) ajuda bastante no entendimento do erro e busca da solução. Neste caso, eu atualizo essa resposta.

Por ora, vamos trabalhar com o que temos :)

Tem alguns itens que precisam ser verificados e que podem ser a raiz do erro:

- A `ConnectionString` com a chave `FarmExternaConnect` não existe ou está inválida no `App.config` (você pode encontrar uma `ConnectionString` válida no site [*connectionstrings.com*](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/))
- Você precisa verificar se a `DLL` do `Provider` está na pasta **Bin**, referenciada no projeto ou se está instalada via *Nuget* (Mais informações no [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7(v=vs.110).aspx) e você ainda pode instalar um pacote via [*Nuget*](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=oracleclient)

Espero ter ajudado \o/

Comment: Fiz uma edição no post original, com o inner exception do erro.

Comment: Tenta postar a sua `ConnectionString` e qualquer tag que esteja relacionado à `Provider` no `App.config` (Não esqueça de alterar os dados de conexão para não expor a sua conexão com o banco :D).  Provavelmente a versão que está definida no `Provider` (`App.config`) é diferente da `DLL` que está no seu projeto (seja direto ou via *Nuget*).

Comment: Postei meu app.config. Minha dúvida é que no cliente funciona e aqui na empresa não. Na nossa empresa usamos o Express 11g. Não sei se isso daria algum tipo de problema.

Comment: Instalei o driver OracleManaged e consegui passar pela linha supra com problemas, mas está dando esse erro: `ORA-12154: TNS:não foi possível resolver o identificador de conexão especificado`. Não sei se isso geraria uma nova thread ou se poderia permanecer nessa atual.